# Problems with setting up Android Studio with Flutter on Mac

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I made my project on Windows computer, now I'm trying to export to ios on friend's Mac. I've been following this tutorial from part 1 all the way to part 5. [How to Install and Setup Flutter for App Development on Mac - Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hL7pkX1Pfko&list=PLSzsOkUDsvdtl3Pw48-R8lcK2oYkk40cm&index=7). In other words, Xcode is installed, Android Studio with Flutter and dart plugin installed as well. Android Studio recognizes both simulator and plugged iPhone. When I open the project in Android Studio it looks like this: [image: image1][image: image2] [image: image3]

Note: Both flutter folder and the project folder are located in "exportalex"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use terminal and hit this: **flutter pub get**

You need to load all the dependency before run app. 
If still you are facing same issue, please run: **flutter doctor**

Then share screenshot of result.